# Converting string to char**

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a problem with my code and i dont know whats wrong :(

I want to convert a string to a char* array and print it out at the end.

The output is currently 3 times the last word of the sentence i entered.

```
void parse(std::string &s, char **argv)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string tmp;

    while(iss >> tmp)
    {             
        *argv++ = (char*) tmp.c_str();        
    }  
}

int main()
{ 
    std::string input;  

    while (1) 
     {                             
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        int argCount = countArgs(input);

        char  *argv[argCount];

        parse(input, argv);        

        for(int i=0; i<argCount; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
        }                      
    }   
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pointer returned by `c_str()` becomes invalid when the string is a) modified, or b) destroyed, whichever comes first. In your case, both happen. All those pointers you stuff into `argv` are invalid by the time `parse` returns.

Comment: Why use naked arrays?  use a `std::vector<std::string>` to put all of the split strings into.

Answer (score 2):

I won't get into details why your current code does not work, because what you are doing is basically not-really-safe/good/sane thing. Please rethink your approach.

**Why use `char*` if you can use `string`?**

If possible, instead of

```
char  *argv[argCount];
...
void parse(std::string &s, char **argv)
...
*argv++ = (char*) tmp.c_str();
```

use

```
string argv[argCount];
...
void parse(std::string &s, string* argv)
...
*argv++ = tmp;
```

it will work almost identically to what you have now, "just" using a different datatype.

However, note that this all will still not be really C++'y, as you are using `string argv[argCount];` with non-constant `argCount`. I'm suprised your compiler actually compiles it, you must be using some C-compliance compilation flag. You should be using `std::vector` or `std::list` to keep an "array of variable length".

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the issues mentioned in the comments by calling `strdup()` before saving your `char *`:

```
void parse(std::string &s, char **argv)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string tmp;

    while(iss >> tmp)
    {             
        *argv++ = strdup( tmp.c_str() );        
    }  
}
```

You'll need to free (not `delete()`) these copies later.

```
for (int i = 0; i < argCount; ++i)
{
  std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
  free( argv[i] );
}
```